# How can you get the server's default page (e.g. index.php) with PHP?

Tags: php, web

Not sure if this is possible. I want to find out what the server's default page value is, so if it is set as "index.htm" or "index.php" then return that. It's for a web app I'm developing; the user has provided their FTP details and website URL (Can this be automatically figured out also?), but then I need to automatically figure out what they're default page is.

I thought of possibly checking files in the FTP directory against the page returned by the URL to see if they match, seems a bit overkill though.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If php is specifically running as an apache module, then a php script can perform a sub request and let apache resolve it for you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-lookup-uri.php

although a common combo, it's just one of very many webserver+php configuration combos.

```
print_r(apache_lookup_uri('/'));
```

Comment: I don't think he will also be running code on the FTP he is connecting to.

Comment: Ideally don't want to be running code on the FTP but this is great method for the majority of cases, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

Because ([as specified here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/change-default-page-for-domain.shtml)) people can set their own custom default indexes.  You could of course look for default.* and index.* (I believe default overrides index), but that wouldn't catch edge cases (like custom directory index).

Comment: Thanks, a partial solution to look for index.php isn't really possible, encase 'index.php' exists but is not the default page.

Comment: I definitely understand that.  I suppose you could have them select in your program if it's default, or custom.  Then allow them to insert a custom value (which, if they set it as a custom name, then they should also know what that name).

Comment: It's a good idea, although I think I will first use chris' apache lookup method, so it's quick for the majority of cases, then move on to this for the remainder of cases.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the domain name as well as an array of all index.* and default.* files, with the file type as the value and the path to the file as the key.

```
<?php
$domain_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo $domain_name.'<br/>';

$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.*');
$files = array_merge($files, glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/default.*'));
$indexes = array();
foreach($files as $index) 
{
    $index_info = pathinfo($index);
    $indexes[$index_info['dirname'].'/'.$index_info['basename']] = $index_info['extension'];
}

echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'</br>';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($indexes); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Much appreciated, but I do not think this solves my initial problem.